# Can't understand the cost function for Linear Regression

Tags: math, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I really can't understand the following equation, especially `1/(2m)`.

What's the purpose of this equation? And where does `1/(2m)` came from?

```
J(theta_0, theta_1) = 1/(2m) * sum_(i=1)^m [ h_theta(x^i) - y^i ]^2
```

Please explain. How it casts???

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding of math and not the programming of math.

Comment: This is in Machine Learning by Andrew Ng professor in Stanford. From his lectures in coursera. This is related to computer science and programming. But if i don't understand it's mathematics then how I can develop machine Learning programs??

Comment: You should use a math site to understand the math, like this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/.  But it looks like you have a good answer now.

Comment: okay yes u r right. For math I'll look for math.stackexchange.com. Thanks

Comment: Note that typing the variables as you do give a wrong impression. For examle the `x^i` you write could better be written as `x(i)` or `xi` since `x^i` gives the impression that x is raised to some power which is not the case.

Comment: Khanacademy has good material on the topic. Look for "linear regression" and "squared error".

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be specific to computer programming in any way. It may be more appropriate on a site about mathematics.

Answer (score 81):

The cost function is

```
J(theta_0, theta_1) = 1/(2m) * sum_(i=1)^m [ h_theta(x^i) - y^i ]^2
```

By `h_theta(x^i)` we denote what model outputs for `x^i`, so `h_theta(x^i) - y^i` is its error (assuming, that `y^i` is a correct output).

Now, we calculate the square of this error `[ h_theta(x^i) - y^i ]^2` (which removes the sign, as this error could be both positive and negative) and sum it over all samples, and to bound it somehow we normalize it - simply by dividing by `m`, so we have **mean** (because we devide by number of samples) **squared** (because we square) **error** (because we compute an error):

```
1/m * sum_(i=1)^m [ h_theta(x^i) - y^i ]^2
```

This `2` which appears in the front is used **only for simplification of the derivative**, because when you will try to minimize it, you will use the steepest descent method, which is based on the derivative of this function. Derivative of `a^2` is `2a`, and our function is a square of something, so this `2` will cancel out. This is the only reason of its existance.

Comment: Okay so nice. This is great answer. I understand now. But one question again if u don't mind. [ h_theta(x^i) - y^i ]^2 is something like (a-b)^2 which is equal to a^2+b^2-2ab. why we do not expand [ h_theta(x^i) - y^i ]^2 like [ h_theta(x^i)]^2 + y^i ]^2 - 2[h_theta(x^i)][y^i]? thanks

Comment: Because this expansion won't lead to any simplification, and only adds additional operations (it is cheapier to compute (a-b)^2 than a^2-2ab+b^2, bacause first one requires 2 artihmetic operations, while the second one - 6).

Comment: Yes but I think the results of both r different. And the correct way for (a-b)^2 is a^2-2ab+b^2, not to subtract b from a first then take square of the result. May be I'm wrong. not pretty sure. Sorry for asking again and again.

Comment: Well, you are wrong. (a-b)^2 is equal to a^2-2ab+b^2, always.

Comment: Great answer. Well explained.

Comment: Is there a reason why we use the square error instead of just taking the absolute value of the difference between h_theta(x^i) and y^i?

Comment: Abs is not differentiable at zero, square penalization is stronger thus converges faster. Also quadratic loss is nocer for theoretical analysis and even has closed form solution. That being said, you can still use abs, simply rememver about these properties

Answer (score 0):

you want to build a model that will evenly distribute the errors across you data points, so the sum of error=0 and the mean of errors=0; you should also build the model that has the smallest errors, which is equivalent to minimizing the mean squared error.